# Erasing Flare is really Keyaru's revenge?

Tags: redo-of-healer

It appears Keyaru just rapes Flare exactly once (as Flare) and then erases Flare to become Freia.

1. **What's the point? Well yeah now you're getting your revenge on Flare's BODY. I don't see the actual revenge on Flare.** Why not just continue to drag Flare around as still Flare? Like somehow Keyaru, now Keyarga, really derives vengeful pleasure from this erasure and just the ONE time ? Or is Flare actually still at the back of Freia's mind trapped in some mind prison?
2. **If the eventual goal to erase Flare to become Freia, then why rape Flare (as Flare) exactly once?** Why not zero times? And if not zero times, then why not, like, 10 times? Is Keyaru really satisfied with exactly one? Or can Keyaru turn on/off the Freia persona, like temporarily bring back Flare for more?

Just finished S01E02: I don't see any indication of an on/off switch or of a mind prison.

**Update:** Just finished s1. Don't really get it except maybe they don't have the luxury of staying in the room forever because eventually they gotta escape and save the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Just finished s1. Don't really get it except maybe they don't have the luxury of staying in the room forever because eventually they gotta escape and save the world.

I guess Keyaru calculated 'Hmmm...I got time for only 1 orgasm and 10 broken fingers. After that I think the guards will come.'

Also... (spoiler for the rest of s1)

> I think there is an on/off just like how Keyaru can switch between Keyaru and Keyaruga and Keara. Then again that's just physical appearance not actual personality.

But...

(spoiler for manga / novel)

> Based on what I've skimmed in the manga and what I read in forums, I think Keyaru, now Keyaruga, does sorta have an on/off switch for Freia / Flare and Ellen / Norn. But idk I don't think Keyaruga used this switch in s1. I think Keyaruga currently doesn't have such power but can eventually obtain such power.

And

> Ultimately, if there isn't a switch, then I think Keyaru thinks like 'Eh sucks, but at least what I did before changing Flare to Freia is pretty good revenge / justice anyway.'